# Hyperledger composer, queries breaking with more than 2 WHERE conditions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Here's my query

```
query Q_BUY_SELL{
  description: "Select filtered Orders "
  statement:
    SELECT namespace.Order
        WHERE ((((orderType != _$filterType AND orderStatus == _$filterStatus) AND bidTokenPrice == _$bidTokenPrice) AND orderer != _$orderer) AND property == _$property )
}
```

And here's how i'm using it

```
return query('Q_BUY_SELL', {
      filterStatus: 'PENDING', 
      filterType: 'SELL', 
      bidTokenPrice: 10, 
      orderer:'resource:com.contrachain.User#o1',
      property:'resource:com.contrachain.Property#p2' 
      })
      .then(function (assets) {
            console.log(assets);
            // Some alterations to assets
```

Here's the only Asset in my db which i wasn't expecting in result because of the 'orderer' field. (See `orderer != _$orderer` in query)

```
{
  "$class": "com.contrachain.Order",
  "orderId": "Thu Feb 22 2018 15:57:05 GMT+0530 (IST)-30",
  "orderType": "BUY",
  "orderStatus": "PENDING",
  "bidTokenPrice": 10,
  "tokenQuantity": 30,
  "orderTime": "2018-02-22T10:27:05.089Z",
  "orderer": "resource:com.contrachain.User#o1",
  "property": "resource:com.contrachain.Property#p2"
}
```

But it's still there in the response in console.

[image]

**TLDR; I have 5 conditions(1,2,3,4,5) in the query `Q_BUY_SELL` out of which (1,5) are working fine but the `2nd, 3rd and 4th` conditions are not being applied to the results.**

I feel silly posting this question as the problem seems trivial, but i've been stuck with this for a while now and need some external perspective to identify what i'm missing here.

**UPDATE: Relevant part of the Models **

```
asset Property identified by propertyId {
    o String propertyId
    --> User owner
}

asset Order identified by orderId {
    o String orderId
    o OrderType orderType
    o OrderStatus orderStatus default = 'PENDING'
    o Double bidTokenPrice
    o Double tokenQuantity
    o DateTime orderTime
    --> User orderer
    --> Property property
}

abstract participant Account identified by emailId {
    o String emailId
    o String name default = ''
    o DateTime joiningDate
    o Boolean isActive default=false
}

participant User extends Account {
    o Double balanceINR default=0.0
}

transaction PlaceOrder {
    o OrderType orderType
    o Double bidTokenPrice
    o Double tokenQuantity
    o DateTime orderTime
    --> User orderer
    --> Property property
}

enum OrderType {
    o BUY
    o SELL
}

enum OrderStatus {
    o PENDING
    o SUCCESSFUL
    o VOID
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its difficult to replicate without the model. But I suggest to 'pare' it back to 4 criteria in your query to begin with (so - remove the property resource comparison for example) and see if it does/doesn't return the orderer (as you wrote). In any case - I would ALSO create a second record so the query does return 'something' that IS EXPECTED to be a match (and hopefully omits the record that shouldn't match), for testing - just so you can see that the query returns an orderer matching your criteria etc etc - bur first try see if the query works with 4 criteria including orderer check. What I'm suggesting is to see if there's a breakage in the aggregation of criteria (or not).

an example of building queries in a transaction and parsing is shown here FYI -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/data/transactions.queries.js

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It is working as expected with 4 criteria (removed the property resource comparison). So there's a breakage, but how can i unbreak it?

Comment: Also, i tried changing `((((1 AND 2) AND 3) AND 4) AND 5)` to `(((1 AND 2) AND (3 AND 4)) AND 5)` , but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: suggest to try a simple `(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5)` as a test please. If it breaks - create an issue at https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues with the evidence and details (including your tests above so it can be replicated). Also I would be interested to see if you tried it with `(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5)` where you use == for all the comparisons (so has to match a field as opposed to NOT EQUAL)  - it should have the same as the first query and break also.

Comment: Tried `(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5)` , only conditions working were `1,5`. Then i tested with `(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 5 AND 4)` and now the working were `1,4` only. I don't know how to raise an issue(Never had to till date), but will try my best. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: And ^this was tested after replacing `!=` with `==`

Answer (score 0):

just to say I don't see the problems you're seeing for multiple criteria - I've tried 5 and six, mixing up - all worked fine?. Perhaps you can give feedback.

I went and tested some queries as follows with parameterised query with criteria (essentially the same as you did, for a different business network) - in online playground (So I create the `queries.qry` file then call the query in my TP function  ( FYI that and the sample function code are at the bottom):

Numbers(below) represent left-side 'fields' in query definition (these fields are shown in the query below (ordinal, left to right)) - my 'data' is at the bottom - essentially I always (except for one test) 'miss out' on a record with tradingSymbol == "1"

```
query myQryTest {
  description: "Select all commodities"
  statement:
      SELECT org.acme.trading.Commodity
         WHERE (tradingSymbol != _$tradingSymbol AND (description == _$description OR description == _$description) AND mainExchange == _$mainExchange AND quantity == _$quantity AND owner == _$owner )

}


}
```

RESULTS:

(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5) - ie all with '==' comparisons.(so 1st criteria would changed to be tradingSymbol == "1" above -*just* for this one test only). All worked fine. 1 record.

(!= 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND = 5) - so one negation in criteria. Worked fine. Got the results I wanted (2 records - see my sample data below)

(!=1 AND (2 = "2" OR 2 == "3") AND 3 AND 4 AND 5) - 6 criteria, as shown above - one in parentheses (where field match is an OR). Worked fine. Got the right results. I changed the description in record 3 to be "4" and I get one record,

{
  "$class": "org.acme.trading.Commodity",
  "tradingSymbol": "1",
  "description": "2",
  "mainExchange": "3",
  "quantity": 4,
  "owner": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#1"
}

{
  "$class": "org.acme.trading.Commodity",
  "tradingSymbol": "2",
  "description": "2",
  "mainExchange": "3",
  "quantity": 4,
  "owner": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#1"
}

{
  "$class": "org.acme.trading.Commodity",
  "tradingSymbol": "3",
  "description": "2",
  "mainExchange": "3",
  "quantity": 4,
  "owner": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#1"
}

you can try this out for yourself - you can try this out with the trade-network from online playground https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/ (deploy trade-network sample) and create a Trader trader 1 record in the Participant.

`/**
 * Try access elements of an array of B assets
 * @param {org.acme.trading.Qry} qry - function to access A elements (and B assets)
 * @transaction
 */
function myQryfunc(qry) {`

return query('myQryTest', {
     "tradingSymbol": "1",
  "description": "2",
  "mainExchange": "3",
  "quantity": 4,
  "owner": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#1"
   })
        .then(function (results) {

```
       var promises = [];

       for (var n = 0; n < results.length; n++) {
        var asset = results[n];
               console.log('Query result is ' + (n+1) + ', object is ' +  asset);
               console.log('Asset identifier is ' + asset.getIdentifier());

       }

   });
```

}

Model definition for my Qry transaction (to call it in playground) is

`transaction Qry {
    --> Commodity commodity`

}

Comment: I tried with your example and got a little happy as it seemed to work fine. Until I tested with the following commodity `{
  "$class": "org.acme.trading.Commodity",
  "tradingSymbol": "1",
  "description": "2",
  "mainExchange": "3",
  "quantity": 5,
  "owner": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#1"
}`
Since the quantity here is 5, it shouldn't be in console log. But it was :(

Comment: Tried with `{
  "$class": "org.acme.trading.Commodity",
  "tradingSymbol": "1",
  "description": "2",
  "mainExchange": "4",
  "quantity": 4,
  "owner": "resource:org.acme.trading.Trader#1"
}` ... still fails i.e. mainExchange filter is not working as well

Comment: what I find strange - is that (in your data, tradingSymbol is "1" - which should have failed (to be returned). So lets try with 2 'negations' -one for tradingSymbol and one for quantity. Can you try with the same `return query` statement  - but in your `.qry` def  add - `WHERE ( (tradingSymbol != _$tradingSymbol) AND (description == _$description AND owner == _$owner AND mainExchange == _$mainExchange) AND (quantity != _$quantity  ) )`  as the condition.

Comment: (continued..) then have 3 records tradingSymbol 1 , tradingSymbol2, and tradingSymbol3 . The latter two should have a quantity of 7. Thus you should get two rows back (!=1 (symbol) and !=4 (quantity). Then change the quantity on tradingSymbol2 record to be 4 - and you should get just one row back (tradingSymbol 3) .NOTE: quantity is a Double field, hence no quotes. All I've done is put parentheses around the negative elements in the definition.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention before. It's not strange as i defined the query(to keep it simple) as `(tradingSymbol == _$tradingSymbol AND (description == _$description OR description == _$description) AND mainExchange == _$mainExchange AND quantity == _$quantity AND owner == _$owner )`